# 5 xbee s2 module with api mode transport API package

Tags: api, xbee

this is my question: 
I have 5 xbee S2, I want to communication with each other.
the setting is

```
coordinator: pan id = 1234 , CH=C ,DH=0000, DL=FFFF ,AP =1, 
router-1: pan id = 1234 , CH=C ,DH=0000, DL=FFFF ,AP =1, JV=1
router-2: pan id = 1234 , CH=C ,DH=0000, DL=FFFF ,AP =1, JV=1
router-3: pan id = 1234 , CH=C ,DH=0000, DL=FFFF ,AP =1, JV=1
router-4: pan id = 1234 , CH=C ,DH=0000, DL=FFFF ,AP =1, JV=1
```

Now I use router1 sent package to router2&3 or coordinator , but it only can receive the package "Transmit Request 0x10" something like :

```
 "7E 00 0E 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FE 00 00 F3"
```

I can't receive other package like:

```
0x00 = "7E 00 0B 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00" ;
0x01 ="7E 00 05 01 01 FF FF 00 FF"...
```

X-CTU setting[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esPWV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Transmit Explicit frame type (0x11) and include the address of your destination node.

https://docs.digi.com/display/XBeeZigBeeMeshKit/Explicit+Addressing+frames